# calling php file using img src

Tags: php, css

i am trying to call a php file using  img src and that php file is having 3-4 div involved.
but when i am calling this php file  i couldn't able to see the result.

actually the php file is more of a html but i changed the extension to php.
code i am using in my php file is :-

```
<div class="onlineWidget">
<div class="count"></div>
<div class="label">online</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

and there is a Css file associated with this file.

Comment: Why are you doing that through an image src? Use ajax instead

Comment: I have problems to understand your question. Image per CSS or per HTML `<img>` tag? Both is now shown in your code. And if your .php file contains no PHP code, then actually PHP is not involved so far.

Comment: If you are trying to embed an image generated by a php script, then you need to set the php script to return the image with the correct mime type.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to show HTML code in an image that is included via img-tags.
It's never possible to just output html code and use this as an image.
You might want to include the PHP file inline or using Ajax or use the [PHP image functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php) to create images that can be embedded via an img-tag.